# How to activate "CPU is always allocated" in a Cloud Run deployment with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy a container in Cloud Run using Terraform. I've already deployed the container manually and run correctly. Now, I need to deploy it with Terraform to make a replicable environment.
I have already managed to configure practically all the parameters, except for this one.

[CPU is always allocated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZsDv.png)

Change this parameter is very easy where I'm deploying manually.

[Manual deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnfTc.png)

But I don't find where configure this parameter in the terraform files, main.tf or variables.tf. I'm using this module: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-cloud-run

Has anyone done it or could help me by indicating if it is possible and where it is configured.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

You have the solution in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#setting).You have to add an annotation, as you can find in the terraform documentation (but not for CPU Throttling), and add the correct entry, like that

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-srv"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
      }
    }

    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "run.googleapis.com/cpu-throttling"      = false
      }
    }
  }
  autogenerate_revision_name = true
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the same if is needed to `startup-cpu-boost`:

`"run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost" = true/false`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `cpu_idle` argument and set it to `false` to make the CPU always allocated.

[Terraform docs here.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_v2_service#cpu_idle)

```
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "foo_bar_service" {
  # various info goes in here such as service name/location
  template {
    # scaling, extra volumes in here
    containers {
      # image, port allocations, environment variables in here
      resources {
        # CPU and memory limits in here, as well as the subject of this question
        cpu_idle = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Thank you to @xtropicalsoothing for correcting me. I had written my previous answer based on the documentation, and their answer was much closer to what I had in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Ash Oldershaw's answer could work for the `google_cloud_run_service` resource (v1), but for `google_cloud_run_v2_service` (v2) I've had to make a couple of adjustments:

- The `resources` block goes *inside* the `containers` block.
- You need to define `cpu-idle = false` to set the CPU to be always allocated. It seems counter-intuitive, I assumed it would be the other way around, but I've tested it and this is how it works.

[Terraform doc here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_v2_service#cpu_idle)

```
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-service"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    containers {
      image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"

      resources {
        cpu_idle = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine and matches what I'd written in my code. I've updated my answer but have my upvote. I wish I'd clarified my original answer earlier and I hope you didn't have to spend too much time working this out!